# How will studying "stochastic process" help me as mathematician??

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes

I wish to decide if I should take a course called "INTRODUCTION TO STOCHASTIC PROCESSES" which will be held next semester in my University.
I can make an un-educated guess that stochastic processes are important in  mathematics. But I am also curious to know how. i.e, in what fields/methods, will basic understanding in "stochastic processes" will help me do better mathematics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[such a similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4165/how-will-studying-stochastic-processes-help-me-as-a-statistician)

stochastic process is very usefull in Acturial Sience, Mathematical finance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something more concrete than Probability Theory:

Mathematical Finance.